# Why doesn't my plot display date and time correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time

I am attempting to create a plot with Temperature on the Y axis, and date and time on the X Axis. My data appears to plot correctly, however the date and time does not. My date and time data is in column 0 of my csv, Labeled  in the format m/d/Y H:M:S, example: 6/13/2022 2:36:00 PM. Instead of this expected format Time appears as simple integers starting from 0 and going up to 10000.

```
#Import libraries
from dataclasses import dataclass
from textwrap import indent
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from datetime import datetime


#read the CSV

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\pmay\Desktop\Python\LOGRPT61.csv", parse_dates=True )
change_format = date_sr.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

#Identify column data
ctrlTC = df.iloc[:,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,]]


#Label Axes
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Temp [deg C]')

#Plot the data
plt.plot(ctrlTC)# kind='line')

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 7]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
line1, = plt.plot([1], label="Control TC1")
line2, = plt.plot([2], label="Control TC2")
line3, = plt.plot([3], label="Control TC3")
line4, = plt.plot([4], label="Control TC4")
line5, = plt.plot([5], label="Control TC5")
line6, = plt.plot([6], label="Control TC6")
line7, = plt.plot([7], label="Control TC7")
line8, = plt.plot([8], label="Control TC8")

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

Which results in:

[Plotted Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqw0p.png)

Updated:

```
#Import libraries
from dataclasses import dataclass
from textwrap import indent
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
import datetime as dt
from statistics import mean
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

#read the CSV
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\pmay\Desktop\Python")


df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\pmay\Desktop\Python\LOGRPT61.csv",parse_dates=['Time'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])






#Identify column data
ctrlTC = df.iloc[:,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
df.info()
Time = df['Time']
#Label Axes
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Temp [deg C]')

#Plot the data

x = Time
y = ctrlTC
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 7]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
line1, = plt.plot([1], label="Control TC1")
line2, = plt.plot([2], label="Control TC2")
line3, = plt.plot([3], label="Control TC3")
line4, = plt.plot([4], label="Control TC4")
line5, = plt.plot([5], label="Control TC5")
line6, = plt.plot([6], label="Control TC6")
line7, = plt.plot([7], label="Control TC7")
line8, = plt.plot([8], label="Control TC8")

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

[New Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCeF4.png)

df sample:

```
                 Time  Loop #1.Process Value  Loop #2.Process Value  \
```

0     2022-06-13 14:36:00                   25.3                   25.0
1     2022-06-13 14:37:00                   25.3                   25.0
2     2022-06-13 14:38:00                   25.3                   25.0
3     2022-06-13 14:39:00                   25.3                   24.9
4     2022-06-13 14:40:00                   25.3                   25.0

I'm uncertain why the format changes to Y-m-D H:M:S, in the CSV it is given as m/d/Y H:M:S. There are 11240 rows in the CSV (counting headers, 11239 without) from 6/13/2022 to 6/21/2022 at 1 minute intervals.

The ultimate goal is to be able to use the code with other historical and future CSVs to produce graphs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code to what I hope is what you need. Some of the key changes are:

1. The date format read from CSV needs to be converted to datetime using pd.to_datetime()
2. The CrtlTC should be just a list of all column names, except Time
3. Date formatter added, which you can use to control the text you want to show in the X-axis, More information [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) if you need it
4. Simplified the code a bit, so that you loop through the line creation process
5. Labels added to legend, so that you can see the customized legend.

Note: As there were only 2 columns of data provided, there are just 2 lines. As mentioned in the question, I have changed the dates in data a bit so that you can see dates from 6/13/2022 to 6/21/2022

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")#,parse_dates=['Time'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H.%M") # Mention how your text data is
#Identify column data
ctrlTC = df.columns[1:] #Should not be iloc, but all columns except DATE

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
for col in ctrlTC:
    df.plot("Time", col, ax=ax)

#dfmax.plot("Date", "max", ax=ax)
#plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Temp [deg C]')
ax.legend(labels=["Control TC1", "Control TC2"], loc="upper left")

# Define the date format
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
date_form = DateFormatter("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M") ## Change this to what you want to show in X-axis DATE labels
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
```

**Output plot**

[image]

Comment: I've made the change and confirmed that my Time column is in a datetime format, but it now shows all time since the epoch and has squeezed my data points into the very end of the graph.

Comment: Please post the new code, the graph and some sample data from `df` in text format (not pic) using which the problem can be reproduced? It is difficult to understand the issue without the data. Thanks

Comment: edited with updates

Comment: @MagicMagnets - The updated code and answer above

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, your answer does produce sensible date formatting. The reason I used iloc is because the CSV contains over 50 columns, most unrelated. When I try using it in place of df.columns in your code I receive a value error: Date ordinal 27585516 converts to 77496-07-30T00:00:00.000000 (using epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00), but Matplotlib dates must be between year 0001 and 9999.

Comment: Deleting the # before dfmax.plot('Time', col, ax=ax) solves the date ordinal problem, and results in a working graph despite creating a undefined name error for dfmax.